# Disable brackets being added to the if conditions in phpfmt plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to disable the setting for adding brackets to the if conditions.

```
if($a == 0)
    echo '0';
```

turns into

```
    if($a == 0){
        echo '0';
}
```

I don't want the brackets to be added.

Answer (score 1):

I think phpfmt doesn't have an option to turn that off.

But in my opinion omitting brackets from condition is a bad practice anyway.

#### For Example

```php
if ($a == 0)
    echo '0';
```

is the same as

```php
if ($a == 0) {
    echo '0';
}
```

#### But

```php
if ($a == 0)
    echo '0';
    echo '1';
```

is the same as

```php
if ($a == 0) {
    echo '0';
}
echo '1';
```

but it looks like it should be

```php
if ($a == 0) {
    echo '0';
    echo '1';
}
```

which it is NOT! So it is always a good idea to use the brackets anyway even if they are not necessary. This will avoid many misunderstandings.

Comment: Former author here. You just explained why there is no option to remove them.

Comment: Yes, the answer is: No you can't disable brackets being added to the if conditions.

Comment: It's supposed to be a formatting package, not a parenting package.

Comment: @AbiusX It is probably not parenting it is probably just following a style guide. Eg. the PSR-2 style guide says for control structures: *"The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces."* So a *"MUST"* is no option you can choose. It's open source, you can fork it, or write a pull request that makes it optional by settings.

Comment: And I specifically deselected the "PSR" compliance in the extension configurations. Not everyone adheres to other people's standards.